# using toggle switch turn led on off

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to change an led image based on a toggle switch position. When I click the toggle switch to on I want the  to change to the redled.jpg and when I click the toggle swith to off I want to change the  to the offled.jpg I sort of have it working using this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Turn LED On/Off Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.switchButton.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <center>
    <div class="slider demo" id="Led-1"><table><tr><td>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
    <td><div id="LedTog1"><img src="./images/offled.jpg" width="30px"  height="30px" style="margin-left: 15px;"/>
        <img src="./images/redled.jpg" width="30px" height="30px" style="margin-left: 15px; display:none"/></div>
    </td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
</center>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.switchButton.js"></script>

<script>

  $(function() {

    $("#Led-1.demo input").switchButton({
      width: 110,
      height: 40,
      button_width: 70
    });

    $("#LedTog1").click(function() {
      $(this).find('img').toggle();
    });
  })
</script>
```

If I click on the switch it slides on/off but does not change the  accordingly but if I click the led it will toggle the led on/off.

I want this to happen when I click the toggle switch not the led.

So basically I want to be able to turn the led on or off when the switch is clicked not the led image itself.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Thank you all for you suggestions.
Just to clarify what I want to do:

[Top image is OFF - Bottom is ON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYYrb.png)

Right now the way it is working is when I click the switch the led **does not** change to **ON or OFF** but when I click the led itself it will turn on or off.

I would like to keep the format as shown in the images above if possible.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="testClick">//Give id to this input

 <script>
 $( "#testClick" ).click(function() {

  $( "img" ).toggle();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Why should he try this? Explain what was wrong in his code and how you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. 
    You can add id in input box and both img tag

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Turn LED On/Off Demo</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.switchButton.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
      </head>
      <body>
      <center>
        <div class="slider demo" id="Led-1"><table><tr><td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="1"></td>
        <td><div id="LedTog1">
            <img src="./images/offled.jpg" id="offled" width="30px"  height="30px" style="margin-left: 15px;"/>
            <img src="./images/redled.jpg" id="redled" width="30px" height="30px" style="margin-left: 15px; display:none;"/></div>
        </td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </center>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script>

      $(function() {
        $("#checkbox").click(function() {

            if($(this).is(':checked')){
                $('#offled').hide();
                $('#redled').show();
                }
            else{
                $('#redled').hide();
                $('#offled').show();
                }
        });
      })
    </script>
```

Comment: Why should he try this? Explain what was wrong in his code and how you fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for your input but, it's not what I'm looking for. I guess I'll have to work this out on my own since no one else has any suggestions. Thanks again for your reply.